# Visualise XML as tree with nodes and edges

Tags: xml

I'm trying to visualise the XML files I'm working with in a specific way. I'm basically trying to make them look like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/klYbaYh.png]

I've tried tools like Oxygen, XMLMarker and BaseX, but none of them really do the trick. I searched extensively on how to do that, but I haven't found anything that suits my needs.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: you could simply style them with CSS

Comment: Would that lead to a format similar to the one in the picture? Thank you for letting the picture show :)

Comment: I am not too good with CSS. It will not be easy and I am not sure if the lines are easy to achieve, but something close to that might work.